# What is causing 15 line bash script to man a file named '0' on exit?

Tags: bash

I have sucked down some files off the web with a bunch of Windows style filenames that include spaces.

To speed things up when I need to search for a file with spaces I wrote a small script.

So instead of typing this:

```
locate -i bad|grep -i file|grep -i name
```

I type this:
    findbadname.sh bad file name

The problem is, that after it runs it leaves a file named '0' (zero) in the directory it was run in.

```
$ ls
$ findbadname.sh this is a bad filename
$ ls
0
```

I can't figure out why. Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/sh
count=0

for a in $@ ; do
    if [ $count = 0 ]; then
            command='locate -i '$a
    fi
    if [ $count > 0 ]; then
            suffix='|grep -i --colour '$a
            command=$command$suffix
    fi
    count=$count+1
done

eval $command
```

I suspect it's the eval command, but don't know what else to try. 
I tried changing `eval $command` to `$($command)`, but it didn't work. I got:

```
$ ./findbadname.sh this is a bad filename
locate: unrecognized option '--colour'
```

I know I can fix the bad file names.  I wrote a script to do that, but these are part of a website that get's updated and has HTML links that would have to be fixed along with it, so for now, I am using this findbadname.sh script.

Comment: What are you trying to do? You certainly don't need to use `eval`, and it's not clear what command line you are trying to build up.

Comment: [ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and [eval is evil](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048)

Comment: The ShellCheck is nice... good link.  I have read that eval is evil, but couldn't figure out another way--tried `$($command)` to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using a `>` sign for comparison, it's redirection.  Use `-gt`.

Comment: That worked.  Is there any reason to switch the `=`  to `-eq` or is it ok the way it is?

Comment: `=` is string equality, `-eq` is numeric equality. If you're intending to compare numbers, use `-eq`

Comment: Usually you can get away with using `=` in place of `-eq`, but consider `[ 3 -eq 03 ]` vs `[ 3 = 03 ]`.